# Is it always possible to choose $x \in (a, b)$ s.t. $\int_a^{x}f=\int_x^{b}f$

Tags: riemann-integration

I am working out a homework problem about Riemann Integrals and the question is as follows:

> Suppose that $f$ is integrable on $[a, b]$, then $\exists \ x \in [a,
>  b] s.t. \int_a^{x}f=\int_x^{b}f$. Is it always possible to choose $x$
>    to be in $(a, b)$?

I have managed to prove the first part and now I am attempting the second part of the question.

This is my reasoning:

Let $f$ be a function such that choosing $x=a$ means $\int_a^{a}f=\int_a^{b}f$.

Now $\int_a^{a}f=0 \implies \int_a^{b}f=0$ and for this to be true, $f$ must be a function defined at only one point, ie $a=b$, which brings me to my question: **is a function defined at a only one point Riemann Integrable** and is the rest of my reasoning correct?

Comment: Well, $\int_a^b f=0$ does not mean that the function is defined only at one point. For example $$\int_{0}^{2 \pi} \sin x \ \mathrm d x = 0$$ and $\sin x$ is defined on the interval $[0, 2 \pi]$.

Comment: But I have chosen $x$ in such a way that $\int_a^xf=\int_x^bf \implies \int_a^af=\int_a^bf$ since $x=a$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, provided that $\int_a^b f\ne 0$.

For example, if $f(x)=x$, and $[a,b]=[-1,1]$, then $\int_{-1}^x t\,dt=\frac{1}{2}(x^2-1)$, while $\int_x^1 t\,dt=\frac{1}{2}(1-x^2)$ and 
$$
\int_{-1}^x t\,dt=\int_x^1 t\,dt\quad\Longrightarrow\quad x=\pm 1,
$$
and hence $x\not\in (-1,1)$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. And regarding my other question, is a function defined at only one point Riemann Integrable?

Comment: Actually, $\int_a^a f$ is DEFINED to be equal to 0, so that $\int_a^b+\int_b^c=\int_a^c$, for all $a,b,c.$